# jboss Address already in use: JVM_BIND localhost/127.0.0.1:8080. fails on windows

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I am getting this error and do not know how to get round it. I am trying to start up the JBOSS server but it is failing.
I am using windows and have tried tasklist/FI "PID eq 8080" at the command line and it just says. INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.

The only thing i can think of is that I have been using net beans to run the glass fish server but I am unsure on how to shut that down as i dont think it has a PID.

any help to resolve and get the jboss server running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS IS NOW SOLVED. It just required obliterating glassfish into smithereens...

Answer (score 0):

There is some other process running, which uses 8080. Make sure to kill it or use

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
</socket-binding-group>
```

option to shift all your ports (also 8080). Just change it to

```
${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:1000}
```

to shift by 1000.